# Turn a C string with NULL bytes into a char array

Tags: c, winapi

I am using `GetOpenFileName` with multiple select capabilities. The files picked are returned in a LPSTR. Inside this LPSTR, the files selected are separated by NULL bytes. I want to split the LPSTR into an array and then loop over that array.

In PHP I would do:

```
 $array = explode("\0", $string);
```

But since I am new to C, I have no idea what I am doing.

Comment: the least you could do is try.

Comment: @Shoosh: I am inclined to agree as its the only way to learn about pointers et al.... ;)

Comment: Bear in mind that most of the solutions here presuppose a double null at the end of the list of files.

Comment: P.S. It is 'NUL' when you are talking about the ASCII character \0.

Comment: What do you mean, the least I could do is try? I had no idea what I am doing, am I just magically supposed to know?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do this to loop through the strings:

```
char *Buffer;             // your null-separated strings
char *Current;            // Pointer to the current string
// [...]
for (Current = Buffer; *Current; Current += strlen(Current) + 1)
  printf("GetOpenFileName returned: %s\n", Current);
```

You can adapt this code to create arrays if it's really necessary.

Comment: Note that this will only work if the LPSTR ends in *two* null characters. Otherwise, it will continue to print out chunks of memory until it happens to run into two consecutive bytes equal to zero, or until it causes a segfault.

Comment: That's true, but the buffer is indeed double-null terminated.  See GetOpenFileName in MSDN.

Answer (score 3):

The easiest thing to do is probably just to loop over the returned strings directly.  (There's no need to create a separate array.)  The code would look something like this (error checking omitted):

```
GetOpenFileName( &ofn );

LPSTR pszFileName = ofn.lpstrFile;

while( *pszFileName != 0 )
{
    // do stuff...
    pszFileName += strlen( pszFileName ) + 1;
}
```

Also, don't forget that if the user selects multiple files, the first entry will be the folder name.

Comment: That doesn't work. It gives me an error about '+=' not able to do a left hand assignment.

Answer (score 1):

Would a string copy do the trick for you?

```
LPSTR ptrFileName;
char buf[100];
strcpy(buf, ptrFileName);
/* Now iterate */
for (int nLoopCnt = 0; nLoopCnt < (sizeof(buf) / sizeof(buf[0])); nLoopCnt++){
   char ch = buf[nLoopCnt];
   /* Do whatever with ch */
}
```

Hope this helps,
Best regards,
Tom.